# How to expose tcp service in Kubernetes only for certain ip addresses?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Nignx ingress [provides](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/) a way to expose tcp or udp service: all you need is public [NLB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html).

However this way tcp service will be exposed publicly: NLB does not support security groups or acl, also nginx-ingress does not have any way to filter traffic while proxying tcp or udp.

The only solution that comes to my mind is internal load balancer and separate non-k8s instance with haproxy or iptables, where I'll actually have restrictions based on source ip - and then forward/proxy requests to internal NLB.

Maybe there are another ways to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

- Do not use nginx-ingress for this. To get real IP inside nginx-ingress you have to set `controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy: Local`, which in its turn changes the way the nginx-ingress service is exposed - making it local to the nodes. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip. This in its turn causes your nginx-ingress LoadBalancer to have unhealthy hosts which will create noise in your monitoring (opposite to NodePort where every node exposes the same port and healthy). Unless you run nginx-ingress as a DaemonSet or use other hacks, e.g. limit which nodes are added as a backends (mind scheduling, scaling), or move nginx-ingress to a separate set of nodes/subnet - IMO each of these is a lot of headache for such a simple problem. More on this problem: https://elsesiy.com/blog/kubernetes-client-source-ip-dilemma
- Use plain Service `type: LoadBalancer` (classic ELB) which supports:

  - Source ranges: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-cidr-ip-address-loadbalancer/
  - `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-extra-security-groups` annotation in case you want to manage the source ranges from the outside.

  In this case your traffic going like `World -> ELB -> NodePort -> Service -> Pod`, without Ingress.

Answer (score 2):

Yo can use the [whitelist-source-range annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#whitelist-source-range) for that. We've been using it successfully for a few use cases and it does the job well.

EDIT: I spoke too soon. Rereading your question and understanding your exact use case brought me to this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3202#issuecomment-658082395), which clearly states these services cannot be whitelisted, and suggests solving this in the firewall level.